# BIDS 2008 R2 execute package I previously created prompts me to save as

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, bids, save-as

I have a project I created with BIDS 2008 R2 bout a month ago.  Today I made some changes to one of the packages inside the project and upon executing the package BIDS prompts me to save as.  Same results clicking the 'Save all' or 'Save Selected Items' buttons.  I have Admin access to the server and hard drive where the project is saved.  I can go to that folder containing the package and create and delete items.  I am able to add existing packages to the project, edit and save them no problem but unable to edit and save the existing package in the project without being prompt to 'Save As'.  I confirmed that I do not have this issue with other projects I created, just this one.

I searched stackoverflow and Google and did not come across any similar questions previously asked pertaining to this specific issue.  Has anyone experienced this as well and were you able to find the cause?

Thank you.

Server Specs:
rdp into SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 Enterprise Edition, 
BIDS 2008 R2, 
Win 8

Comment: `2008 BIDS` is a funny bugger, close the bids, and open it again `As Administrator` see if this helps. Also if you have some custom windows layout setup in BIDS, reset them, as funny as it may sound but in some cases it does help :)

Comment: Turned out to be a case of "User forgot".  Working on so many projects at once, sometimes talking about it jogs the memory.  Thanks for your reply sir, I greatly appreciate it.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the explanation.  The project was created on a local machine and at some point was transferred to the server.  I resolved the 'Save As' issue by first opening the project, then in windows explorer navigated to the project folder and deleted the packages, then went back to BIDS and saved the project.